# ssh connection failed via php

Tags: php, ssh, web-server

ssh connection failed via php

Trying to connect to ssh using a php script via a webserver.
I work on a MacOsX.
I changed apache's User and Group (_www:_www) to my own User and Group ().
The command I use is this (I changed connection details):

```
ssh -v -p 2222 -i /Users/myname/.ssh/id_dsa_mykey -l myuser 10.1.12.10 2>&1
```

From a terminal, no problem, it connects and gives the following output:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.1.12.10 [10.1.12.10] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/myname/.ssh/id_dsa_mykey type 2
debug1: identity file /Users/myname/.ssh/id_dsa_mykey-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 0c:bd:4e:da:17:28:d2:a6:20:b9:11:a3:de:91:f0:ce
debug1: Host '[10.1.12.10]:2222' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/myname/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /Users/myname/.ssh/id_dsa_mykey
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 434
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 10.1.12.10 ([10.1.12.10]:2222).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
...
```

However, from a php script, it gives the following output:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.1.12.10 [10.1.12.10] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/myname/.ssh/id_dsa_mykey type 2
debug1: identity file /Users/myname/.ssh/id_dsa_mykey-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 0c:bd:4e:da:17:28:d2:a6:20:b9:11:a3:de:91:f0:ce
debug1: Host '[10.1.12.10]:2222' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/myname/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /Users/myname/.ssh/id_dsa_mykey
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 434
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I think that the problem comes after that line:

```
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 434
```

With the terminal, it can connect:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

But from php it fails:

```
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
```

I don't know why, because the webserver has the same user and group as me when I execute the command
on the terminal.

---

SOLVED by HBruijn

So I created a new ssh key pair, and... it worked. 
Mohahahaaaa, I'm too powerful now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this : `debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured`

You private ssh key is secured with a passphrase, which I guess isn't a problem from the console, as your console session has acces to your ssh keychain, but apache doesn't. Since you don't run the ssh command from a terminal but from PHP ssh also can't prompt for the passphrase (nor for the regular password).

Comment: Thanks, so I will try to create a key without a passphrase...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say you changed Apache's User to your own? Do you mean you're running Apache as yourself? Or that you changed _www's UID to match your own?

Did you restart Apache after making these changes? Try executing `id` from within php to see what the current effective IDs are.

Your error sounds like it's describing not being able to open `/Users/myname/.ssh/id_dsa_mykey` which is pretty normal behaviour for anyone other than `root` or `myname`

Comment: What do you mean when you say you changed Apache's User to your own? I added those lines in the httpd.conf: User myusername
Group staff

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making the changes? You can tell if they've taken effect by running a page with `<?php echo exec('id'); ?>`

Comment: Yes, I did restart Apache. I just solved the problem: it was the fact that the ssh-agent was used by the terminal, but not by apache.

Comment: Well it's always sad to hear that I was wrong, but I'm glad you have it working now :)